# Refresh linear referencing layer that's based on a database view, without closing ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, linear-referencing

**Background:**

I have a linear referencing event layer that was created using the `Make Route Event Layer` geo-processing tool.

- The `Input Route Features` are in a standard feature class, but the
  `Input Event Table` is a **database view** (both from the same Oracle
  geodatabase).
- The `Event Type` is set to
  `POINT`, and the `Measure Field` uses the `MIDPOINT` field in the database view.

I've used the
   database view as the `Input Event Table` so that I can symbolize a point at the midpoint of my linear referencing events.

```
--ENG.EVENTS_MIDPOINT_VW
--Calculates the midpoint measure between the from and to measures.

SELECT 
    ROAD_ID
    ,FROM_MEAS
    ,TO_MEAS
    ,(TO_MEAS-FROM_MEAS)/2 AS MIDPOINT
FROM 
    ENG.EVENTS
```

**The Problem:**

When I make edits to the underlying table, they are not reflected in the linear referencing event layer, even after refreshing the map. The only way I've found to get the linear referencing event layer to refresh, is to restart ArcMap. This is not ideal.

Oddly, the attribute table of the database view (not the linear referencing event layer) **does refresh** just fine in ArcMap, after edits are made to the underlying table. But, for some reason, the linear referencing event layer doesn't reflect the edits.

**The Question:**

How can I get a linear referencing event layer that's based on a database view to reflect edits made in the underlying table?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think k you need to recreate the event layer by re- running the tool. The event layer seems to be a snapshot of the view at the time of execution.

Comment: Good thinking. I suppose I could make a model or script that would re-generate the linear referencing layer.

Comment: What happened when you tried the suggestion of @BenSNadler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit ArcGIS Desktop's registry to use the `NO CACHING` option:

[How To: Set up CACHING and NO CACHING for route event tables](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006530)

> Starting at ArcGIS 8.3 SP3, there is an option to select one of two
>   algorithms for drawing event tables in ArcMap. The choices are CACHING
>   (default) or NO CACHING. These options can improve performance or
>   allow for additional functionality.
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap\DynSeg] 
>   "UseOptimization"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the advice of @BenSNadler:

> Just a guess, but I think you need to recreate the event layer by re-
>   running the tool. The event layer seems to be a snapshot of the view
>   at the time of execution.

Comment: Recreating the event layer did the trick. The crazy part is, it takes longer to run the `Make Route Event Layer` geoprocessing tool, than it does to close and re-open ArcMap.

Comment: I was hoping that copying and pasting the event layer in the ArcMap table of contents would work (refresh the underlying view). Unfortunately, it doesn't. I guess the copied event layer still references the same 'snapshot from the view' from the original event layer.