# InsertCursor on a event table (linked to linear referencing) not displayed directly on the map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase, python-addin, linear-referencing

I have a Python script (Python add-in) that creates new entries (with InsertCursor) in an event table that was used for linear referencing (through Display Route Events). The table is stored in a file GDB.

My first problem is linked to this question:

[Refreshing open attribute table in ArcMap using ArcPy rather than ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/refreshing-open-attribute-table-in-arcmap-using-arcpy-rather-than-arcobjects)

the table is not reflecting the edition, except if I close the table tab and relaunch it, or if I sort an attribute of the table. I have tried all solutions exposed in this question. But that’s OK, I can deal with a manual refresh.

My main problem is that the entries I have created are “dead datas”: they are not represented in the map. My only solution is either to close the mxd and relaunch it, or edit them again, and then the segment created is shown.

I have tried to edit the layer (not the table), to update the entries directly after their creation (in the same script), to recreate a new event layer (display route events) and to change to "da" cursors, but the problem remained.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact data storage format in use. I expect you'll find that only true databases will passively flush data contents for subsequent reread.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! It can be a good explanation, i will try on SDE to see if it is working. But if anyone have a workaround for such edition on file GDB I take it :-)

Comment: By "edition" I think you must mean editing.

Comment: exactly! sorry if my words are not always well chosen.

Comment: I have similar, but different question here: [Refresh linear referencing layer that's based on a database view, without closing ArcMap](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/219990/6257)

Comment: I have tried with a table stored in ArcSDE / SQL Server (non versioned), and the problem is exactly the same. @Wilson Yes, our questions are quite similar! I hope one of us will get a solution :-)

Comment: I came up with an answer which might be what you're looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247703/62572

Comment: @Wilson Perfect! Works like a charm, thank you very much for the information! Not even slowing down events representation.

Comment: Glad to hear it.